# How to manage instances and class instantiations therein

Tags: c#, instance, instance-variables

Let's say I have two classes.
One class `User` which has a lot of instances and one `AccountInterface` which is handling Database/File System Queries and might be accessed by every user.

Lets say, `User` looks like this:

```
public class User
{
    public User(string uID)
    {
        this.UID = uID;
    }
    AccountInterface AccountInterface = new AccountInterface();
    public string UID {get;private set;}
    private string _Alias;
    public string Alias
    {
        get
        {
            if (Alias.IsNullOrEmpty())
                this._Alias = AccountInterface.GetAlias(this.UID);
            return this._Alias;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._Alias == value) return;
            AccountInterface.UpdateAlias(this.UID,value);
            this._Alias = value;
        }
    }
}
```

From my Understanding, each new instance of User will create a new instance of AccountInterface. Could this impose negative effects? Is this the proper way to handle multiple Instances?

I have had many simillar encounters in my projects and always ask myself if this is how things are done. For example, I have a program reading from a ticket system. After all I am able to modify/edit each instance of a ticket with `someTicket.Description = "new Description"` or `someTicket.WriteComment("Some comment")`

I wonder if it's better to build all logic into the interface class and work like
`TicketInterface.WriteComment(someTicket, "Some Comment")` or `TicketInterface.ChangeDescription(someTicket, "some description")`.

I find the first Method more clean and intuitive as I can have general code in the Interface (Such as `TicketInterface.GetAllTickets()` ) while having instance specific code such as `someTicket.WriteComment("Some comment")` within the Instance. I believe this might cause negative impact, for example by opening a new Database Connection for each new Instance of an Object.

Comment: Just a few things outside the actual question: It is not the User class's business to know whether or not an alias is taken. `if (this._Alias == null || this._Alias == "")` - that's what [string.IsNullOrEmpty()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-6.0) is for ... And for that whole functionality: That's what [Lazy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=net-6.0) is for ... :)

Comment: @Fildor Why not throw in a property setter?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Wouldn't you be surprised by that?

Comment: @Fildor No, if it had been provided an invalid value. Now if a property getter threw an exception I would be surprised.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay oompf. You're right... grabbing a coffee...

Answer (score 1):

As `AccountInterface` is managing tasks which are not required to be bound to another class instance you could make `AccountInterface` a `static class` or implement the `singleton pattern` in an `static` context.

```
public static class AccountInterface{
     public static WriteToFile(string output){...}
     public static WriteToDb(object obj){...}
}
```

Or

```
public static class AccountContext{
     private static AccountInterface _interface;
     public static AccountInterface Interface { 
         get { return _interface; }
         set
         {
             if(_interface == null) _interface = value;
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> From my Understanding, each new instance of User will create a new instance of AccountInterface. Could this impose negative effects? Is this the proper way to handle multiple Instances?

Maybe? It is perfectly reasonable for a object to instantiate other objects on constructions. One thing that seem odd is that AccountInterface does not take any parameters, in some cases this is perfectly fine, but in some cases it suggests that the class and the methods it contain should be 'static'.

If `AccountInterface` has any dependencies it might be better to use [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection). I.e.

```
public User(string uID, AccountInterface accountInterface)
{
    this.UID = uID;
    this.accountInterface = accountInterface;
}
AccountInterface AccountInterface;
```

And let a dependency injection framework take care of resolving any dependencies. If you have any static dependencies this can help avoid these, since it lets all components in the DI container share a object, instead of sharing the same object in the entire program.

In your ticket example, a typical design would use a *ticket repository* that is responsible for loading and saving tickets. Once a ticket has been loaded it can be modified using the properties and methods on the ticket, and once done it would be saved back to the repository. So `GetAllTickets` would be part of the repository class, but `WriteComment` would be part of the ticket class.

When accessing resources remotely it can be somewhat more common with a interface like `TicketInterface.WriteComment(ticketId, comment)` since that would be very easy to translate to a webrequest, and it can avoid downloading a somewhat large objects when you do not need all the data it contain.